# How to get a unique filename in perl

Tags: perl, temporary-files

I want to create in a directory many small files with unique names from many processes. Theoretically filenames may be the same, so how do I account for that? What module I should use for this purpose? Files should be persist.

Comment: You could generate a GUID and use that as the basis for your file name (e.g. add an extension). See http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Data-UUID-1.217/UUID.pm

Comment: Are the files temporary or should they be persistent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append a timestamp to each file, up to the millisecond:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my $timestamp = int (gettimeofday * 1000);
print STDOUT "timestamp = $timestamp\n";
exit;
```

Output:

```
timestamp = 1227593060768
```

Comment: Realized my first example didn't do the timestamp correctly, so use the Time::HiRed module.

Answer (score 14):

You probably want to use [`File::Temp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) for that.

```
($fh, $filename) = tempfile($template, DIR => $your_dir, UNLINK => 0);
```

Comment: won't the files created by File::Temp disappear when the process ends?

Comment: @ennuikiller Apparently there is an `UNLINK` option.

Comment: File::Temp closes files after writing ?

Answer (score 6):

The package to use would be [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html).

Answer (score 4):

Without any modules you could use something like this: `time() . "_" . rand()`

Answer (score 3):

$$ contains the process id of the running perl program.  Therefore it can be used in file names to make them unique at least between instances of the running process.